# Hide SCNFloor but show shadow with SceneKit (swift)

Tags: ios, scenekit

I am trying to display a shadow of my character on a map I have. I have a *ambient* light and an *omni* light. If I add a floor, it shows the shadow/reflection, but the floor covers the map.
[image: With Floor]

Without a floor, I don't get any shadow/reflection.
[image: Without Floor]

I add floor like this:

```
floor = SCNFloor()
floor.reflectionFalloffEnd = 10
floor.reflectivity = 0.5
let floorNode = SCNNode(geometry: floor)
floorNode.position = SCNVector3(x: 0, y: -1.0, z: 0)
self.rootNode.addChildNode(floorNode)
```

The map is created with Mapbox iOS SDK (MGLMapView).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your screenshots I don't see any shadow. I only see the reflection. For shadows you need either a directional or spot light. For the reflections over your map did you try to the the map texture to your SCNFloor? Another option is to use a SCNFloor with a material transparency of 0 but that will have a cost due to the overdraw.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I could apply the map texture on the SCNFloor, but the map is constantly changing depending on where the user is. Therefor the texture is dynamic and can't be applied. 

Changing the materials transparancy to 0 did work. It casts a reflection like it should! But changing the omni to a spot, doesn't seem to cast a shadow. There is still only a reflection. Do you know why?